# xml.etree.ElementTree getElementByID()?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

How to get the equivalent of `getElementByID()` with the Python library `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

There seems to be a method called `parseid()` but my tree is already parsed. I don't want to parse it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it myself:

```
tree.findall('''.//*[@id='fooID']''')[0]
```

Better or other solutions are still welcome. :-)

Comment: That is correct, but I'd recommend third party libraries for xml parsing. You should take a look at Beautifulsoup and lxml.

Comment: @VincentBeltman why? I parse XML, AFAIK Beautifulsoup is for parsing HTML which is sometimes broken. Why is lxml better? Speed is not important for me in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works indeed, but performance can be quite abysmal as - my guess is, I didn't verify this, perhaps also related to the complexity of xpath - the tree is traversed on every to `findall()`, which may or may not be a concern for your use case.

Probably `parseid()` is indeed what you want if performance is a concern. If you want to obtain such an id mapping on an existing tree, you can also easily perform the traversal once manually.

```
class getElementById():

    def __init__(self, tree):
        self.di = {}

        def v(node):
            i = node.attrib.get("id")
            if i is not None:
                self.di[i] = node

            for child in node:
                v(child)

        v(tree.getroot())


    def __call__(self, k):
        return self.di[k]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used this to drastically speed up `get_element_by_id`. To use this with `lxml.html`: `get_by_id = getElementById(htmlElement.getroottree()); get_by_id('id')`